# Can I run the 32-bit version of TrueCrypt effectively on OS X 64-bit?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, truecrypt

I've been thinking about TrueCrypting my hard drive on my MacBook. However, I've noticed there is only a 32-bit version of TrueCrypt for OS X.

Will installing this on a 64-bit operating system cause me to bog down my OS to run in 32-bit mode or will my computer function perfectly fine after using it?

Comment: Running x86 programs on your x64 OSX should not make your system run slower, although it might make the program run slower. There might be a way to encrypt disks using the baked in disk utility. Have you tried this?

Comment: Well true crypt is on the fly encryption which means everything will be going through truecrypt.

Comment: NVM. True crypt just came out with a 64bit version today. :)

Comment: Post this as an answer and accept it once possible. Otherwise the system considers this question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

> True crypt just came out with a 64bit version today.

-- [user646655](https://superuser.com/users/96358/user646655)

Comment: @user646655 if you return and post an answer, do flag this for deletion.